# get center in Google map in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I added a google map in my app. It shows path from source to destination.

I also want to show estimated Time,legth of that path as below:

[image: Estimated Time]

How can I calculate center of path with google map?

Thank you for your valuable time!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Would the center of the bounding rectangle be good enough?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

let coordinateA = CLLocation(latitude: 55.0, longitude: 35.0)

let coordinateB = CLLocation(latitude: 65.0, longitude: 73.0)

let distanceInMeters = coordinateA.distance(from: coordinateB)

Once you calculated the distance, use this formula to calculate the speed.

i.e.,  speed = distance / time

try this delegate to get speed or time

**func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])**